# Show label and image if tableview is empty

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created solution when tableView is empty then show label "No data available" else show content. However I am not able to show background image AND label together. What I am doing wrong?

This is how I do it:

```
var numOfSections: Int = 0
        if reviewsArray.count != 0{

            tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
            numOfSections = reviewsArray.count

        }
        else{
            let noDataLabel: UILabel     = UILabel(frame: CGRect(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, tableView.bounds.size.height))
            noDataLabel.text             = "No data available"
            noDataLabel.textColor        = UIColor.black
            noDataLabel.textAlignment    = .center
            tableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel
            tableView.separatorStyle = .none

        }
```

And in viewDidLoad I add background image with blur:

```
let blurredBackgroundView = BlurredBackgroundView(frame: .zero)
        tableView.backgroundView = blurredBackgroundView
        tableView.separatorEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(blurEffect: blurredBackgroundView.blurView.effect as! UIBlurEffect)
```

Please do not suggest any third party library :)

Comment: You are overwriting the background image with the label. You need to create a new `UIView` with the background image and label. Then set that as the `tableView.background` when `reviewArray` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the background view to blurredBackgroundView, and then to noDataLabel. By setting it to noDataLabel, you are getting rid of blurredBackgroundView.

I'd try adding noDataLabel as a subview of the background view. Like:

`tableView.backgroundView.addSubview(noDataLabel)`

Comment: Awesome, I am still getting familiar with subViews and all that stuff. But it did work, thank you very much :)

Comment: I can do it after 5 mins